# how to print two txt files line by line in python using for loop

Tags: python

My codes are listed as following:

```
import time
f = open("q1", "r")
g = open("q2", "r")

f1 = (f)
f2 =(g)


for y in f1:
  for x in f2:
     print(y)
     sleep(1)
  print(x)
```

The output does not print line by line,but prints the whole file. How to print both files line by line?

output

```
1
2
3
4
5
a
b
c
d
e
```

desired output

```
1
a
2
b
3
c
4
d
5
e
```

Comment: What your code is saying is: "for every line in f, print all the lines in g". Which of course can't happen because the first time through `g` it is exhausted and won't print anything next time.

Comment: Does it answer the question? [Reading a File Line by Line in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53283718/reading-a-file-line-by-line-in-python)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reading two text files line by line simultaneously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11295171/reading-two-text-files-line-by-line-simultaneously)

Comment: I'm not sure that the code you posted will give the output you listed.

Answer (score 0):

You meant to iterate through both files at the same time which is what `zip()` gives you:

```py
for y,x in zip(f1, f2):
    print(y)
    print(x)
```